# expo/vector-icons not responding

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, vector-icons

In my react-native project, I've imported icons from expo/vector-icons and it's been going well until now. I made the same import, but it's not being implemented at all in the project, and there is no error. The vector-icons is just not responding.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.